# Getting Row from Gridview in Dev Express?

Tags: devexpress, gridviewrow

How do I get a Row from a Gridview control in DevExpress?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did some digging for you, and it seems like [this](http://cs.rthand.com/blogs/blog_with_righthand/archive/2008/02/23/LINQ-to-XtraGrid.aspx) is the best way to do it.

Comment: thnx, but still wondering why implementing a bunch of classes to do something that was achieved with a single line of code?
Isn't it stupid, even why it MAY be performant?!?!

Comment: No doubt. I'm not being glib, but perhaps you shouldn't use the DevExpress tools if they aren't easy to implement? Why not use a control that is easy to implement and extend? ASP.NET's ListView control will give you a lot of power, and is relatively easy to implement.

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to achieve?
Do you want to get instance of object displayed as grid row?
If so, try GridView.GetRow() method.

Answer (score 2):

if you're not trying to do what przemaas has to say, then operate on the object that you're binding to (cause really, that's what the xtragrid is all about). If it's an xpcollection(T) that you're binding to, then any operations done on the records within it will propagate to the grid through the PropertyChanged event on the xpcollection.

If you're binding to a custom collection, then just inherit it from IBindingList and/or implement INotifyPropertyChanged.